# How does css grid layout works

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

I was wondering how does the Css grid layouts. I thought I was getting close to understand it until I tried this below.

I thought it would make the item 5 go behind the 3 since it has no position defined in the grid, but instead it went after the item 3, what is the behaviour behind it?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GOPvXO\

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
}

.wrapper div{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1){
  background-color: blue; 
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(2){
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(3){
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(4){
  background-color: lightblue;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(5){
  background-color: pink;
}
.wrapper div:nth-child(6){
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. Interesting question. As far as i can see youre mixing up flexbox and css grids here. I found this guide very helpful in understanding how the system works, so i may help you too: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/. The site also offers a guide about flexbox which i think i super useful: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[W3C docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#auto-placement-algo) and [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-the-auto-placement-algorithm-in-css-grid/) can help you understand why grid works this way.

Let's look at how grid-items are placed according to *8.5 Grid Item Placement Algorithm* in docs:

**0. Generate anonymous grid items**

No anonymous items - none grid items generated

**1. Position anything that’s not auto-positioned.**

On this step only **element 4** is positioned

```
grid-column-start: 2; /* second column, span 1 */
grid-row-end: 4;      /* third row, span 1 */
```

**2. Process the items locked to a given row.**

There are no items locked to specific row, so none positioned

**3. Determine the columns in the implicit grid.**

Number of columns in your explicit grid is 3.
There are no items that will need more than 3 columns - elements 1,2 and 4 do not need more than 3, all the rest have no explicit columns specified, which means that number of columns in your implicit grid is 3

**4. Position the remaining grid items.**

In your case algorithm works according to default “sparse” packing:

> Set the column-start line of its placement to the earliest (smallest
>   positive index) line index that ensures this item’s grid area will not
>   overlap any occupied grid cells and that is past any grid items
>   previously placed in this row by this step.

At this point you have five elements yet to be positioned: 1,2,3,5 and 6.
Auto-placement cursor now is on start-most row and column, that is row 1 and column 1. Step by step explanation how all remaining items are placed:

- Position **element 1** (definite column position) in row 1, col 1-2, Auto-placement cursor moves to row 1 column 3.
- Position **element 2** (auto-position on both axis) in row 1, col 3, Auto-placement cursor moves to row 2 column 1 since there are only 3 columns.
- Position **element 3** (definite column position) in row 2, col 2, Auto-placement cursor moves to row 2 column 3.
- Position **element 5** (auto-position on both axis) in row 2, col 3, Auto-placement cursor moves to row 3 column 1.
- Position **element 6** (auto-position on both axis), Auto-placement cursor is on row 3 column 3.

---

If you want element 5 to go behind 3, you have two ways of doing it:

### Solution 1: set `grid-auto-flow: dense;`

This way after placing **element 3** Auto-placement cursor's will go to start-most row and column lines in the implicit grid - which is row 2 column 1.

Same will happen with **element 6**, so it'll be placed in row 2 column 3.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: pink;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

### Solution 2: explicitly define row for element 3

This way **element 3** will be placed on step 1 of the algorithm, and step 4 will go like this:

- Position **element 1** (definite column position) in row 1, col 1-2, Auto-placement cursor moves to row 1 column 3.
- Position **element 2** (auto-position on both axis) in row 1, col 3, Auto-placement cursor moves to row 2 column 1 since there are only 3 columns.
- Position **element 5** (auto-position on both axis) in row 2, col 1, Auto-placement cursor moves to row 3 column 3, since row 2 column 2 is already occupied
- Position **element 6** (auto-position on both axis), Auto-placement cursor moves to row 3 column 1.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-rows: 50px 50px 50px;
}

.wrapper div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 4;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: pink;
}

.wrapper div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```